# HAProxy failing over to a "busy" page

Tags: haproxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change backend when reaching maxconn HAProxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/406433/change-backend-when-reaching-maxconn-haproxy)

I want our HAProxy configuration to fail over to the backup server in the backend, or to another specified backend, in the event that maxconns is reached on all backend servers.

This is to display a static over capacity message that I'll serve up from another server.

From what I can tell by reading the backup server is only used if the backend servers are all "down", not when they are full of traffic.

How can I accomplish this behaviour?

Comment: Does this do what you need? http://serverfault.com/questions/406433/change-backend-when-reaching-maxconn-haproxy

Comment: I shall give that a go tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, answer taken from [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/406433/change-backend-when-reaching-maxconn-haproxy).

```
acl too_many be_sess_rate gt 10
use_backend b_too_many if too_many be_sess_rate
```